# Switch button default always showing 'NO'

Tags: php, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with switch field in prestashop 1.6. When I implemented default is showing NO, I want default to be Yes. can someone help on this?

```
/* isparent array */
      $is_parent_array = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'is_parent_on',
            'value' => 1,            
            'label' => $this->l('yes')            
            ),
        array(
            'id' => 'is_parent_off',
            'value' => 0,
            'label' => $this->l('No')            
            )

        );


//switch field
 array(
        'type' => 'switch',
        'label' => $this->l('Is Parent'),
        'name' => 'is_parent',
        'is_bool' => true,
        'values' => $is_parent_array,        
        ),
```

Comment: How do you load the values for this form? Is it an object?

Comment: @sadlyblue There is a model that I defined all values needed in the form and in controller I am executing $this->_join .= 'LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'organization org ON (org.id_organization = a.id_parent)';
    $this->_select .= 'a.org_name AS org_name,a.id_parent AS id_parent,a.is_parent AS is_parent,a.id_country AS id_country,a.id_state AS id_state,a.address1 AS address1,a.address2 AS address2,a.city AS city,a.postcode AS postcode,a.date_add AS date_add,a.date_upd AS date_upd, org.org_name AS parent';   like normal prestashop workflow

Comment: So if it's the controller it will load the object related. In that case you need to default the object var to true when defining the object vars. If you need more help, please post the object.

Comment: model- class OrganizationModel extends HierarchyCustomObjectModel
{ 
  public static $definition = [
  'is_parent'        => ['type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'db_type' => 'int(11)'] 
  ],
  ],
  ];   
  public $is_parent;  
  ;   
}

Comment: controller- /* isparent array */
  if(empty($results) || ($org_parent_id==0 && $org_parent_id!="")){
      $is_parent_array = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'is_parent_on',
            'value' => 1,
            'checked' => 'checked',
            'label' => $this->l('yes')            
            ),
        array(
            'id' => 'is_parent_off',
            'value' => 0,
            'label' => $this->l('No')            
            )
        
        );
  } 
}

Comment: controller continuation -   array(
        'type' => 'switch',
        'label' => $this->l('Is Parent'),
        'name' => 'is_parent',
        'is_bool' => true,
        'values' => $is_parent_array,        
        ),


    ),

Comment: you should edit the post and include the code for better reading. anyway, in the OrganizationModel try public $is_parent = true;

Comment: @sadlyblue I am sorry for adding in comments, your solution works, thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `default_value` parameter to true or false (true in your case, false is default):

```
array(
    'type' => 'switch',
    'label' => $this->l('Is Parent'),
    'name' => 'is_parent',
    'is_bool' => true,
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'is_parent_on',
            'value' => 1,
            'label' => $this->l('yes')
            ),
        array(
            'id' => 'is_parent_off',
            'value' => 0,
            'label' => $this->l('No')
        )
    ),
    'default_value' => true,
),
```